# Access data from an actual API service in protractor tests

Tags: json, angularjs, protractor

I am writing end-to-end tests using Protractor for an Angular application. The application uses an API service to retrieve data from the back-end and this data is then used to populate pages in the Angular application.

I would like to utilize this API to get data to use in my jasmine tests, the tests will confirm that the back-end data is correctly and completely populated on applicable pages in the UI. I definitely DO NOT want to mock the server, I want to hit the actual server and work with the actual data from the JSON response.

My question is 2 sided; how to call the API service from my protractor tests and secondly, how to retrieve data from the JSON response from this API.

Any (detailed) information, examples you can provide as to how this can be done would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is used to test the ui of an application.  What it does is click buttons and enter text in text boxes and wait for responses.  For example if I have a login form and want to test the scenario when a user enters an email address wrong and an error message pops up.  Protractor would navigate to the email field, enter an incorrect email address and then find the element that contains the error and verify the error showed up.

So as long as you have an environment setup that has a ui connected to an API service, the API service will be called as normal.  Protractor will click buttons and if a button click triggers a call to the API service it will go straight to that service.

As for the JSON response access, this is probably not a good use for protractor.  Protractor is used to click events and wait for responses.  So if you are displaying that JSON response in some form or way protractor could verify it is displayed.  For example, if you are displaying some data from the server in a table on a button click, you could have protractor click that button and verify the table has the correct values.  But you would not want to verify the JSON object is as expected.  That would be unit-tests on the API itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response @link13, but what 'am trying to do in this case is that very verification of what is displayed on different pages in the application based on the API calls that are made. The application under test has a lot of data pulled in and displayed on its pages and I just want to make sure the data is not being truncated or shortened in an way before it gets displayed in the UI (e.g. the API shows 100 widgets in the JSON response, but I only see 10 widgets displayed on the widget listing page)

Comment: I was curious to know if you have done this or what route you took? I am working on tests doing the same thing and was wondering your methods?

Answer (score 0):

We have two options

1. Make a request by `require(...)` and using a `request` library.
   This allows you to make [direct HTTP Service calls](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/), as discussed in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319610/how-to-make-http-getpost-request-in-protractor)
2. Use some data from a .json file by `require(...)` it directly:
   https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/978#issuecomment-47250364