# How to make HTTP GET+POST request in Protractor

Tags: jquery, node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am facing problem to send HTTP get request in Protractor. Actually, I need to check data in DB after perform some action in UI.

It will be very helpful if I will be able to do it using JQuery, but I am not able to find a way how to use JQuery inside Protractor.

Need Help !!

Actually, we did try to use the Node.js lib as shown below, but facing problems in it.

```
var http = require('http');

var json_data;

http.get('SiteUrl', function(response) {
    var bodyString = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on("data", function(chunk) {
        bodyString += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {

        json_data = bodyString;
        console.log("1---->" + json_data);
    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("There is an error in GET request");
});
console.log("2---->" + json_data);
```

After Debugging, we have found that the problem is Protractor is not waiting for HTTP request to be complete and just pass on. We are getting `2---->` first in console and then `1---->`.

Comment: Ajax request to a URL specifically for this operation? Shouldn't be difficult, though I don't know protractor

Comment: Actually, protractor is for E2E testing for AngularJS application. We are not able to make Ajax request, I think knowledge of Protractor is essential to answer this question.

Comment: The 'end' function with log1 is async, so it's pass logicaly after the log2...

Comment: it's not the job of the EndToEnd test (via Protractor) to check the backend !
You should write Integration Test Suite or Unit Test Suite for the backend side.

Comment: So, do you have solution for this ?

Comment: @JatinSeth, Have you solved this issue? I am also having same problem, can you please share the solution if you have it.

Answer (score 5):

I also use *http* module (for different purpose, for reinitialization of the database).

To make protractor wait for ending the request, use promises

```
var http = require('http');

var json_data;

http.get('SiteUrl', function(response) {
    var bodyString = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on("data", function(chunk) {
        bodyString += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        json_data = bodyString;
        console.log("1---->"+json_data);
        // All the processing and Angular code should be here
        console.log("2---->"+json_data);
    });

}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("There is an error in GET request");
});
```

If you don't like putting all the data processing into *response.on('end')* callback, then make callback a separate function.

Additionally I have to say that Protractor is not intended to be used to check the database directly. It is for end-to-end testing. You should better build a complex scenario which writes some data on one of the page, go to another page and expects that data is updated.

Comment: To expand on the part about making Protractor wait, there are a couple things you can do. You can pass a `done` function to `beforeEach` or `it`, e.g. `beforeEach(function(done) { doMyPromiseStuff.then(done) }`.  Or, you can add a task to the control flow. You'll need to use http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.call.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access to jQuery (it's frontend side) from protractor, because a Protractor test suite is just a NodeJS script (it's backend side).
So you can use the NodeJS HTTP API (or another request lib).

Check this example : http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/

Comment: Actually, we did try to use the lib as shown below, but facing problems in it.
        var http = require('http');

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://testurl.com/endpoint/test/',
    headers: {'id': 'ABCD',
        'sessionid': 'dummyId',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-us'
    },
    body: '{ "pay_load": [] }'
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body);
        console.log(info);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the right answer which you are looking for. You have not mentioned that db name.

I am using http://frisbyjs.com/ to get documents from couchdb (document database) in my protractor project and it fulfill my purpose very well.

Comment: We are using Elastice search as DB, we just need to hit a URL to fetch data from there.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question on Protractor git issue page, but they were not able to reply my question; so, I found an alternative for this. I broke my test case into 2 test cases. In 1st, I just clicked the button and in 2nd I was able to fetch json and perform validation on it.

Answer (score -1):

What about something like this?

http://eitanp461.blogspot.com.ar/2014/01/advanced-protractor-features.html

This post proposes to reuse an already existing AngularJS module to insert data into the DB using addMockModule function.

This could be modified to inject a new AngularJS moudule as a mock with all the features you want, like checking stuff, inseeting data, etc. 
As this is an angular module/service it should use the AngularJS http module thus Protractor will know how to handle it.

Disadvantages? Well this probably need an AngularJS context to run, don't know if it will work in non angular apps (or sections of it, like a non agular login).

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question and say that this is probably overkill, I think @NicoPennec had it correct the whole time. The link he posted (http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/) has a good example.